# App versions duplication

Tags: ios, xcode, project-management, code-duplication

I have a problem, I have several versions of the same application but the process of duplicating and managing several duplicate applications is becoming very complex, each copy gets unique features by client demand.

What methods are used to simplify this process?
Do I need to have detailed documentation about every App?

I'm trying to separate the code by modules and had them according to the clients demand, am I on the correct path?

Sorry for the bad English, any question just ask, I'm always online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be managed in your code revision system. Git and Mercurial allow you to manage code as "change sets". You could have a branch for each client, and have a main branch (trunk) where you add features for everybody. In the client branches, you add feature sets for individual clients. If you want to merge them back to the trunk, you can. You can also merge from the trunk to branches.

Of course, it's important to develop in a modular way in order to facilitate this approach. Also, unit tests speed things along when you have to merge.